# How do I turn Vi colors off in Ubuntu Linux 14.04

Tags: syntax-highlighting, colorscheme, linux, bash

How do I turn vi colors off? I was using vim-tiny on on Ubuntu 14.04. Installed vim-nox. Version is version 7.4.52. Once I installed that, I got all these syntax colors by default. I have my Terminal set to a black background with bright green text. Now when I use vi with the colors, some of the text is unreadable against the dark background. I would rather just turn the colors off. How do I do this?

Comment: Side note: you might want to explore the vim color themes as well. Perhaps you'd find one that looks nice with your settings. Type `:color` and tab through the possible arguments. I use a black background for my terminal (with gray text) and I personally like the `desert` theme.

Comment: Syntax highlighting is off by default. If you don't want it, why do you even enable it?

Comment: @Shabaz Thank you for your helpful remarks. I will explore the themes, and maybe find something appropriate. :-)

Comment: @romani You are incorrect. Sytntax colors were enabled by default when I installed vim-nox. If I knew how to enable/disable them I wouldn't have asked the question, naturally. I edited my question to better explain what happened.

Comment: @romainl On Debian, the detault `/etc/vim/vimrc` has `syntax on`.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker it does? In my case (Ubuntu 14.04), it is commented out. (pretty much the entire file is commented out, except `runtime! debian.vim`, and `source /etc/vim/vimrc.local`). `/usr/share/vim/vim74/debian.vim` has other things. but nothing about `syntax`. `/etc/vim/vimrc.local` is for the sysad to make.

Comment: @muru Oops, it's indeed commented out on *Debian*, but on Ubuntu 15.10 it's enabled. Guess this changed between 14.04 and 15.10...

Comment: @muru  All I know is that on my system, the syntax colors appeared after I installed vim-nox on 14.04.  I did not explicitly enable them, so it must have been a default setting.

Comment: @gracious1 Nope. `/etc/vim/vimrc` is provided by `vim-common`, which is a dependency of `vim-tiny`. That file was already present when you installed `vim-nox`. It's just that `vim-tiny` has `compatible` set, so it doesn't do syntax highlighting. vim-nox doesn't have compatible set, so any existing `syntax on` or `syntax enable` took effect when you ran that. You, or someone else sharing your computer, has `syntax on` in a startup file.

Comment: Oh, no, I was wrong. I'm using pi-rho's PPA, and pi-rho does have it commented out where Ubuntu's `/etc/vim/vimrc` doesn't. Looks like @Carpetsmoker was right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use:

```
:set t_Co=0
```

This will tell Vim that you're not using a colour terminal. The difference with using `:syntax off` is that this will still enable *some* syntax highlighting features with bold, underlined, and "reverse video".

Comment: Hmm... I think I still want to see bold. I think I was able to see bold and some other formats with vim-tiny, so I wouldn't want to completely lose functionality. Thanks for your helpful answer.

Comment: @gracious1 *This* will enable bold/underline, `:syntax off` *won't. ;-)

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant!

Answer (score 5):

Just discovered this after viewing `/etc/vim/vimrc` for the first time. Uncommenting the line "`set background=dark`" in `vimrc` solves my readability problem also. It changes the syntax colors so that they are distinguishable against my black background! This is actually better than what I had hoped for in the original question!

(Presumably `:set background=dark` would have worked, too? Or something like that?)

Comment: Yes, `:set background=dark` would have worked. You could add that to `~/.vimrc` or `~/.vim/vimrc` as well, instead of modifying files in `/etc`.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable syntax highlighting by doing:

```
:syntax off
```

To turn it back on:

```
:syntax enable
```